# Internal error while creating bugzilla new account

Tags: php, email

Bugzilla has suffered an internal error. Please save this page and send it to karthik.hansi@infysky.com with details of what you were doing at the time this message appeared.

URL: http://localhost:88/createaccount.cgi?login=karthikhanasi12345%40gmail.com

There was an error sending mail from 'bugzilla-daemon@' to 'karthikhanasi12345@Gmail.com':Can't call method "address" on an undefined value at C:/Program Files (x86) /Bugzilla/perl/perl/site/lib/Email/Send/SMTP.pm line 25.

Comment: place the code that is located (x86)/Bugzilla/perl/perl/site/lib/Email/Send/SMTP.pm line 25.

Comment: that is showing only address not the 'bugzilla-daemon@'    i didn't get where that file is located .

Comment: huh, you should be able to open the file SMTP.pm

Comment: yeah, I opened but what to change in that.

Comment: Post the code here